# "export 'Params' was not found in '@angular/router'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-router

In my angular app, I have imported Params from angular/router for many times.
Only in a particular component I am getting this error: `"export 'Params' was not found in '@angular/router'`

Code:

```
import { Params, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//It works fine in parent component while gives warning in a child component
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

My angular specs:

[image]

Comment: That's a *warning*, not an error, and it's pretty clearly wrong: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/82798e9d048c239251793110f0c3059307caf3a0/packages/router/src/index.ts#L23. I sometimes get similar warnings, but the app seems to work anyway!

Comment: The app is broken, only a blank screen is shown.

Comment: And do you see the same problem in the console? Do your tests pass?

Comment: Yeah in the terminal and browser console same warning appears. I am new at angular so I an unaware of testing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you even import Params in your code. I assume you're using it to receive parameters during the navigation. I never explicitly import Params, e.g.

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.productID = route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
```

Starting from Angular 4, I use ParamMap instead:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.productID = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }
```

If none of the above solves your problem, put a breakpoint in your code and see if the `route.snapshot.params` contains the expected value - the problem may be on the sending part (the parent route).